# How to mark packets by program

Tags: networking, iptables, packet

**How to mark all packets (inbound and outbound) for specific program/ cmd in Linux using iptables or any other firewall/ tool**

Given that --cmd-owner option was deprecated ref:http://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter/msg49716.html.

For example, how to mark all Firefox's packets, knowing that Firefox can spawn processes so the PID option isn't feasible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution using [`cgroups` `net_cls`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/net_cls.txt) subsystem to group certain processes group, mark the packets in this `cgroup` using the  `iptables` rule with the **match extension**, and then use `tcpdump` to monitor the packets from this cgroup. by listening to an `nflog` interface.

## Preperations

### Creating a cgroup in the `net_cls` subsystem

```
$ mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/firefox
```

### Add the relevant pid to the cgroup

The best way, to ensure that all related pids are grouped, is to do so **before** you start running the application.

For instance, if you want to run firefox, first check the pid of your current shell (`echo $$`). Then add it to the cgroup you created.

```
$ echo <pid> > /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/firefox/tasks
```

All the process spawning from your shell will now be assigend to the "firefox" cgroup.

### Assigning a class id to the cgroup

From the documentation of the [`cgroups` `net_cls`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/net_cls.txt):

> You can write hexadecimal values to net_cls.classid; the format for
> these values is 0xAAAABBBB; AAAA is the major handle number and BBBB
> is the minor handle number.

```
echo 0x100001 > /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/firefox/net_cls.classid
```

## Mark those packets in an `iptables` rule

`iptables` has [match extensions](https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/iptables/iptables-extensions.8.en.html#MATCH_EXTENSIONS) that you can leverage:

> **MATCH EXTENSIONS**
>
> iptables can use extended packet matching modules
> with the -m or --match options, followed by the matching module name;
> after these, various extra command line options become available,
> depending on the specific module.

You use the [cgroup](https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/iptables/iptables-extensions.8.en.html#cgroup) extension module, and mark those packets by assigning the [NFLOG](https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/iptables/iptables-extensions.8.en.html#NFLOG) as a  group target:

> **NFLOG**
>
> This target provides logging of matching packets. When this target is
> set for a rule, the Linux kernel will pass the packet to the loaded
> logging backend to log the packet. This is usually used in combination
> with nfnetlink_log as logging backend, which will multicast the packet
> through a netlink socket to the specified multicast group. One or more
> userspace processes may subscribe to the group to receive the packets.
>
> `--nflog-group nlgroup`
>
> The netlink group (0 - 2^16-1) to which packets are (only applicable for nfnetlink_log). The default value is 0.

So it would look something like (take the net_cls.classid you created, and decide of some number to the nflog group):

```
$ iptables -I INPUT 1 -m cgroup --cgroup 0x100001 -j NFLOG --nflog-group 123
$ iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m cgroup --cgroup 0x100001 -j NFLOG --nflog-group 123
```

This rule would mark all the incoming/outgoing packets in the cgroup with a `nflog` group number 123.

## Run `tcpdump`

You can use the `nflog` interface. Not all versions of `tcpdump` support this. You can check if your versions does:

```
$ tcpdump --list-interfaces |grep nflog
5.nflog (Linux netfilter log (NFLOG) interface) [none]
```

If it does, you can listen to all the packets in this interfaces, which are the packets sent/received by the processes in the cgroup you created:

```
$ tcpdump -v -i nflog:123
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! isn't this approach marking only packets originating from my device (outbound)? Is there a way to mark inbound packets, it seems like there must be a way since the destination of that packet is a local socket and we can get the program name (or PID) that has created it with `ss` command.

Comment: @user216385 It's marking both inbound and outbound packages. Notice there are two `iptables` commands - one to the `INPUT` chain and one to the `OUTPUT` chain.

Comment: I've set up both iptables rules, but it's only recording outbound packets from the process, no inbound ones.  The process is the PowerDNS recursor, and the traffic is just UDP port 53 traffic.  Then I added the pid of DNSdist that the recursor is mainly getting packets from, but still no inbound packets are found!  Most frustrating.  Any ideas?