# How do you mark both incoming and outgoing packets to a cgroup v1 net classifier?

Tags: iptables, cgroups, tcpdump

I'm attempting to isolate and tcpdump all network traffic from a single
process, following the instructions here:([How to mark packets by program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/743436/how-to-mark-packets-by-program)):

```shellsession
$ sudo bash
# mkdir                             /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls 
# mount -t cgroup -onet_cls net_cls /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls

# mkdir              /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/tcpdump
# pidof my_program > /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/tcpdump/tasks
# echo 0x100001    > /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/tcpdump/net_cls.classid

# iptables -A INPUT  -m cgroup --cgroup 0x100001 -j NFLOG --nflog-group 123
# iptables -A OUTPUT -m cgroup --cgroup 0x100001 -j NFLOG --nflog-group 123
# tcpdump -i nflog:123
```

However, it's doing a poor job, as it's only showing outbound traffic, not incoming traffic:

```shellsession
# iptables-save -c | grep cgroup

[0:0] -A INPUT -m cgroup --cgroup 1048577 -j NFLOG --nflog-group 123
[4242:623034] -A OUTPUT -m cgroup --cgroup 1048577 -j NFLOG --nflog-group 123
```

As it was intended to be used with Traffic Control (tc) which only cares about outbound traffic, is this by design, or is it a defect?

Regardless of the answer to that question, is there a better way to log all the packets going to/from a given process (or set of processes)?

PS: The command `tcpdump -i nflog:123 not src host x.x.x.x` keeps saying

```
tcpdump: NFLOG link-layer type filtering not implemented
```

even though I'm not asking for link-layer filtering.  What's up with that?

Thanks in advance!